# jQuery nested each/Ajax issue

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, jquery

I have nested `each` loops but an Ajax request in the second loop seems to not be adding to a variable that I declare in the first loop.

This is an example ("personal" information excluded) of what I am using:

```
var pages = [["Page Title 1", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]], ["Page Title 2", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]], ["Page Title 3", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]]];

function loadFeeds() {
$.each(pages, function(index, page) {
    $(".pages").append("<a class=\"pagename\" href=\"#" + page[0] + "\">" + page[0] + "</a>");
    html = "<div class=\"page\" id=\"" + page[0] + "\">";
    $.each(page[1], function(index, feedUrl) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: feedUrl,
    processData : true,
    data: {
        tagmode: "any"
        },
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        html += "Some header HTML";

        $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(i,entry) {
            if (entry.image_urls.length === 0) {
                html += "HTML from the data";
            }
            else {
                html += "More HTML";
            }

            if ( i == 34 ) return false;
        });
        html += "Closing tags from the header";
        afterAjax();
        // console.log(html); returns correct information here
    },
            error: function(x,y,z) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
    // console.log(html); returns everything declared to html OUTSIDE of the ajax request
    });
        $("body").append(html + "</div>");
    // Also tried: $("body").ajaxStop(function(){ $(this).append(html + "</div>"); }); because Ajax is asynchronous
});
}​
```

Any ideas as to what is going on?

**EDIT:**

Full non-working demo, WIP page functionality: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/u42uy/

Full working demo, no page functionality:

Full screen: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/LXkaN/embedded/result/
Normal: http://jsfiddle.net/SO_AMK/LXkaN/

Please note that these are without images and are not the full app.

Comment: The html variable data never makes it outside of the Ajax function. It is as if it isn't there but the requests are being made. (See inline comments)

Comment: The thing is the actual send/receive does not happen right away. When you call `ajax`, it is only setting up the request. You might well have returned from `loadFeeds()` function before any of the request has completed. One solution is to keep a count of number of received requests, and append the whole thing to the body when count = number of feeds. Or just insert them into the page as they arrive instead of waiting for all.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ajaxStop is not firing because jsonp requests are by default not global. See [here](http://bugs.jquery.com/ticket/8338)

I've updated your fiddle that forces jsonp requests as global. http://jsfiddle.net/u42uy/3/

*edit typo

Comment: Thank you very much, how do you make them global?

Comment: With this code jQuery.ajaxPrefilter(function( options ) {
    options.global = true;
});

Answer (score 2):

**The Issue**

Looks like a [race condition](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Race_condition). Remember that AJAX runs asynchronously and thusly, the `success` handler will run at some point in the future after the AJAX response has been received successfully. While the AJAX request is dispatched the rest of the script is executing. Specifically speaking:

```
$("body").append(html + "</div>");
```

Is running before the success handler is fired; meaning your `html` variable has not been updated at all yet.

**Solution 1**

Move

```
$("body").append(html + "</div>");
```

Within your `success` handler.

```
    html += "Closing tags from the header";
    afterAjax();
    // console.log(html); returns correct information here
    $("body").append(html + "</div>");
},
```

**Solution 2 ($.ajaxStop)**

Ensure that you register your handler before your make your `$.ajax()` calls. This will ensure your AJAX requests don't fire and finish before your code that registers your handler for `.ajaxStop`.

```
function loadFeeds() {
    html = "";
    $.ajaxStop(function(){$(document.body).append(html + "</div>);

    $.each(pages, function(index, page) {
        $(".pages").append("<a class=\"pagename\" href=\"#" + page[0] + "\">" + page[0] + "</a>");
        html = "<div class=\"page\" id=\"" + page[0] + "\">";
    ...
}
```

**Solution 3 (From your jsLint+Deffereds)**

This example is taken from your fully working jsLint link. This code takes all of the `$.ajax` requests being created in your loop and stores in them in an arrary to be latter applied to a `$.when().done()` call. `$.when()` will inspect each `$.ajax` request applied to it and when it is done, call the handler specified in `$.done()`. Each `$.ajax` request stores its response in the `html = []` array that is defined at the start of `$.ready()`. When the defered check (`$.when()`) sees all the `$.ajax` requests have completed we then join the array (`array.join('')`) to make 1 big HTML block and append it to the document. We then call your `afterAjax()` function.

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var html = [];
    var feeds = ["http://pulsesubscriber.appspot.com/items?feed=http://feeds.gawker.com/lifehacker/vip&jsonp=?",
                 "http://pulsesubscriber.appspot.com/items?feed=http://allthingsd.com/feed&jsonp=?",
                 "http://pulsesubscriber.appspot.com/items?feed=http://feeds.cnet.com/latestnews/pulse&jsonp=?"];
    loadFeeds(feeds);

    function loadFeeds(feeds) {
        var requests = [];

        $.each(feeds, function(index, feedUrl) {
            requests.push($.ajax({
                type: "GET",
                url: feedUrl,
                processData : true,
                data: {
                    tagmode: "any"
                    },
                jsonp: "jsonp",
                dataType: "jsonp",
                success: function(data) {
                    var feedElements = "<header class=\"feed-title\"><div class=\"feed-title-content\"><span class=\"feed-title-text\">" +
                        data.responseData.feed.title +
                        "</span></div></header><section class=\"row\"><div class=\"scroll-left\"></div><div class=\"row-scroll\">";

                    $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(index,entry) {
                        var feedElements = '';
                        if (entry.image_urls.length === 0) {
                            feedElements += "<div class=\"tile no-img\"><title class=\"tile-title no-img\">" +
                                entry.title +
                                "</title><hr class=\"no-img hr\" /><span class=\"no-img excerpt\">" +
                                entry.contentSnippet +
                                "</span><div class=\"tile-modal\"><div class=\"article-wrapper\">\r\n<div class=\"article-header\">\r\n<a class=\"article-title-link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" +
                                entry.link +
                                "\">\r\n<h1 class=\"article-title\">" +
                                entry.title +
                                "</h1>\r\n</a>\r\n<h2 class=\"article-byline\">By " +
                                entry.author +
                                ": " +
                                data.responseData.feed.title +
                                "</h2>\r\n</div>\r\n<hr class=\"article-hr\"/>\r\n<div class=\"article-content\">" +
                                entry.content +
                                "\r\n<a class=\"read-more\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" +
                                entry.link +
                                "\">Read More...</a>\r\n</div>\r\n</div></div></div>\r\n";
                        }
                        else {
                                feedElements += "<div class=\"tile\"><img class=\"tile-image\" src=\"" +
                                entry.image_urls[0] +
                                "\" /><title class=\"tile-title\">" +
                                entry.title +
                                "</title><div class=\"tile-modal\"><div class=\"article-wrapper\">\r\n<div class=\"article-header\">\r\n<a class=\"article-title-link\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" +
                                entry.link +
                                "\">\r\n<h1 class=\"article-title\">" +
                                entry.title +
                                "</h1>\r\n</a>\r\n<h2 class=\"article-byline\">By " +
                                entry.author +
                                ": " +
                                data.responseData.feed.title +
                                "</h2>\r\n</div>\r\n<hr class=\"article-hr\"/>\r\n<div class=\"article-content\">" +
                                entry.content +
                                "\r\n<a class=\"read-more\" target=\"_blank\" href=\"" +
                                entry.link +
                                "\">Read More...</a>\r\n</div>\r\n</div></div></div>\r\n";
                        }
                        html.push(feedElements);
                        console.log('updated elements');
                        if(index == 34 ){
                            return false;
                        }
                    });
                },
                error: function(x,y,z) {
                    console.log(x.responseText);
                }
            }));
        });

        $.when.apply(this,requests).done(function(){
            console.log('when!');
            console.log(html);
            $(document.body).append($(html.join('')));
            afterAjax();
        });

    }



    $("#refresh-all").click(function(){
        $("body > header, body > section").remove();
        $("body").removeClass("active");
        loadFeeds();
    });

    function afterAjax() {
            $(".page:first").addClass("active");
            $(".tile").click(function(){
            if ($(".tile-modal.tile-modal-active").length) {
                $(".tile-modal.tile-modal-active").removeClass("tile-modal-active");
                $(this).children(".tile-modal").addClass("tile-modal-active");
            }
            else {
                $(this).children(".tile-modal").addClass("tile-modal-active");
                $("body").addClass("active");
            }
        });


        $(".scroll-left").hover(function(){
            $(this).parent().animate({scrollLeft: 0}, 7000);
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().stop();
        });

        $(".scroll-right").hover(function(){
            $(this).parent().animate({scrollLeft: $(this).siblings(".row-scroll").width()}, 7000);
        }, function() {
            $(this).parent().stop();
        });
    }
});
```

If you would like to execute a series of requests and once they have all executed do another action, you can utilize [Futures & Promises Pattern](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Futures_and_promises) or deffereds. In jQuery this is done in via [`.promise()`](http://api.jquery.com/promise/)(Futures/Promises) or [`.when()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.when/) (Deffered).

**A Note on Global Variables**

It is also worth noting that not use `var html = ...` makes your variable a global; which is generally frowned upon. It would be best once moving `$("body").append(html+"</div>")` within the success handler to also declare `html` as `var html`.

Comment: Please read the inline comments that say that I already tried `$("body").ajaxStop`.

Comment: `.ajaxStop()` does nothing if there are outstanding requests. If you make a request and then call `.ajaxStop()` before the requests return, the handlers are not executed. You still have a race condition with a caveat of an attempted `.ajaxStop()` call.

Comment: You can't use `.ajaxStop()` it doesn't do what you think it does. You are not understanding that you are mixing synchronous and asyncronous scopes. Your handles are executed immediatly after the scope where you are calling $.ajax. Meaning that you are using your `html` variable before your Ajax completes. You CAN NOT use `.ajaxStop()` to make anything happen. You must change how your code is written, it is blatantly broken in its current state.

Comment: As per the jQuery documentation: "**Description: Register a handler to be called when all Ajax requests have completed. This is an Ajax Event.**" that is exactly what I want.

Comment: Make your call to $.ajaxStop before your $.each loop that calls $.ajax. Your AJAX requests might be finishing before your handler is registered.

Comment: I already tried that as mentioned above. I am posting two full demos

Comment: You also have to move your definition of `html` to be in the same scope as the definition of your handler. See solution 2 and this JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/pqzJC/21/

Comment: Based on your jsFiddle I supplied a working example. Please not I changed your `alert`s to `console.log`s. I also localized all globals to your on load handlers where I could. This way it should not pollute the global window space. I am also not 100% sure on how to verify the output. I just made the assumption you want `afterAjax` to fire when all the responses have been completed. My jsFiddle is here: http://jsfiddle.net/LXkaN/21/

Answer (score 1):

Unless your ajax calls are synchronous (and I see no signs that they are), your each loop will finish and return BEFORE the ajax calls success functions run.  You CANNOT structure your code this way.  That means that `$("body").append(html + "</div>");` will run before the ajax calls get a chance to add anything to your `html` variable.

You need to think about ajax response callbacks as independent pieces of code that run on their own timing sometime after your `.each()` loops are done and design the handling of the responses with that assumption in mind.  Also keep in mind that multiple ajax calls aren't even guaranteed to complete in the order they were sent.

You could order the ajax calls by sending one and not sending the next until that one completes, keeping the combined html in a string variable like you have and then in the completion function of the last ajax call, you append the final accumulated html string to the body.

Here's another problem.  At the start of your first `.each()` loop, you have this;

```
html = "<div class=\"page\" id=\"" + page[0] + "\">";
```

That reinitailizes the `html` variable, overwriting any results that might already be in there.  You need to initialize it once before any .each() loop.

Comment: Please read the inline comments that say that I already tried `$("body").ajaxStop`.

Comment: @A.M.K - and what exactly was the result when you used `ajaxStop()`?

Comment: Absolutely nothing happened vs. data declared outside of the ajax request being appended.

Comment: @A.M.K - If you need guaranteed execution order, then you need a total rewrite that either issues these requests one at a time or collates all the responses into a data structure that can then be sorted into the right order when the last ajax call is done and then inserted into your document.

Comment: Please reread the question and inline comments, _this is not an asynchronous issue_. Even if I disable the async it still happens, I am posting a full demo.

Comment: @A.M.K - and please reread the additional problem I added to my answer.  Your logic is completely wrong if it's not async because you're reinitializing the html variable each time through the start of the first loop throwing away any previous data.

Comment: Yes, it gets appended to the body.

Answer (score 0):

Do the follow:

- Add `var html = ''` after `var pages` (line 1);
- Change `html =` to `html +=` (line 6);
- Add `html = ''` after `$("body").append(html + "</div>");` (line 41).

Result:

```
var pages = [["Page Title 1", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]], ["Page Title 2", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]], ["Page Title 3", ["Page URL 1", "Page URL 2", "Page URL 3"]]];
var html = ''; // ADD THIS

function loadFeeds() {
$.each(pages, function(index, page) {
    $(".pages").append("<a class=\"pagename\" href=\"#" + page[0] + "\">" + page[0] + "</a>");
    html += "<div class=\"page\" id=\"" + page[0] + "\">"; //ADD THE +

    $.each(page[1], function(index, feedUrl) {

    $.ajax({
    type: "GET",
    url: feedUrl,
    processData : true,
    data: {
        tagmode: "any"
        },
    jsonp: "jsonp",
    dataType: "jsonp",
    success: function(data) {
        html += "Some header HTML";

        $.each(data.responseData.feed.entries, function(i,entry) {
            if (entry.image_urls.length === 0) {
                html += "HTML from the data";
            }
            else {
                html += "More HTML";
            }

            if ( i == 34 ) return false;
        });
        html += "Closing tags from the header";
        afterAjax();
    },
            error: function(x,y,z) {
                alert(x.responseText);
            }
        });
    });
        $("body").append(html + "</div>");
        html = ''; // RESET HTML TO NEXT Each
});
```

Comment: You need `html` from first or second each to be reseted?

Comment: A better explanation might be needed. I am creating three inline "pages" that will use content from multiple JSONP sources. So, I have a loop that runs through each of the three pages and creates a second loop that runs through each of the sources for that page, gets them and processes them. the HTML structure ends up being: (modified) `<main-container><page-container><content>`Lorem Ipsum...`</content></page-container><page-container><content>`.....`</main-container>`